# Error 'Request failed with status code 502' while making GET request to archive URL using axios

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, axios, request

As explained in the docstring, this minimal reproducible example makes GET requests to the given archive URLs, logs the response data, and logs any errors that occur. While trying to make a GET request to the archive URL using axios, an error is being thrown. The error is 'Request failed with status code 502'.

**Code:**

```
/**
 * Makes GET requests to the given archive URLs, logs the response data, and logs any errors that occur.
 * 
 * This program makes GET requests to the archive URLs in the `archiveUrls` array. The response data is ,
 * logged and any errors that occur during the requests or while logging the response data are logged 
 * as well. The errors are logged using the winston library's error level.
 */

const axios = require('axios');
const winston = require('winston');

/**
 * Creates a logger for logging errors.
 *
 * @constant logger
 */
const logger = winston.createLogger({
  level: 'error',
  format: winston.format.json(),
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.Console({ format: winston.format.simple() })
  ]
});

/**
 * Makes a GET request to the given `archiveUrl` and returns the response data.
 * If the request fails, logs an error and throws an error.
 *
 * @function fetchArchive
 * @async
 * 
 * @param {string} archiveUrl - The URL of the archive to fetch.
 * 
 * @throws {Error} If the request fails.
 * 
 * @returns {object} The response data.
 */

async 
async function fetchArchive(archiveUrl) {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(archiveUrl);
    return response.data;
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error while fetching archive: ${error}`);
    throw error;
  }
}

/**
 * Makes GET requests to the given archive URLs, logs the response data, and logs any errors that occur.
 *
 * @function main
 * @async
 * 
 * @throws {Error} If there is an error parsing the JSON.
 */

async function main() {
  try {
    const archiveUrls = [
      'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/stolelaf88/games/2021/03',
      'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/puchov/games/2014/03',
      'https://api.chess.com/pub/player/tennessi/games/2020/08'
    ];
    // Note: archiveUrls can be found at the value fields of the https://api.chess.com/pub/player/${username}/games/archives with key "archives."



    for (const archiveUrl of archiveUrls) {
      console.log(`Fetching archive from URL: ${archiveUrl}`);
      const archive = await fetchArchive(archiveUrl);
      console.log(archive);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    logger.error(`Error parsing JSON: ${error}`);
  } 
}

main();
```

I tried to make a GET request to the archive URL using axios and was expecting an array whose indices are individual game dictionaries. Instead, I am returned an error.

**Expected:**

```
 {
      url: "string", // URL of this game,
      pgn: '"string", // final PGN,
      time_control: "string", // PGN-compliant time control,
      end_time: 1254670734, // timestamp of the game end,
      rated: "Bool" //whether the game is rated or not,
      fen: "string", // final FEN,
      time_class: "string", // chess.com time control category,
      white: [Object], // details of the white-piece player,
      black: [Object], // details of the black-piece player
    }
  ]
}
```

**Error:**

```
error: Error while fetching archive: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 502
error: Error parsing JSON for username stolelaf88: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 502
error: Error parsing JSON for username stolelaf88: AxiosError: Request failed with status code 502
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is likely that you are calling the API from a frontend component. API calls don't work well from the frontend due to CORS.

Using your code on the backend works fine. [Consider this Node.js  implementation sandbox][1] like this which works:

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "node-axios-winston",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.html",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon index.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Wesley LeMahieu",
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^1.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.20",
    "winston": "^3.8.2"
  }
}
```

**index.js** - using your code from above but I added a delay to see things.

I also notice the 3rd URL is actually a broken link now.

Comment: I think that was a simple copy and paste error. I don't have an extra async there in my version that compiles. I'll edit the post. Thanks for trying to figure it out!

Comment: That makes sense I should have assumed that would have been easily spotted. Is this a frontend or backend component? What framework/environment? I'm assuming Node.js.